# "item_translation is not associated to item!" Sequelize error

Tags: javascript, associations, sequelize.js, feathers-sequelize

I am running a simple query on two tables which are supposed to be associated, but I keep getting the following message:

> item_translation is not associated to item!

Basically `item_translation` is supposed to belong to `item`. According to the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongsto), I have done everything correctly. Here are the models:

ItemTranslation model:

```
module.exports = function () {
  return function (app) {
    /** @type {Sequelize.Sequelize} */
    const sequelize = app.get('sequelize')

    const ItemTranslation = sequelize.define('item_translation', {
      _id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      sourceId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'item',
          key: '_id'
        },
        onDelete: 'cascade',
        onUpdate: 'cascade'
      },
      text: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    }, {
      freezeTableName: true
    })

    ItemTranslation.associate = function () {
      ItemTranslation.belongsTo(sequelize.models.item)
    }
  }
}
```

Item Model:

```
module.exports = function () {
  return function (app) {
    /** @type {Sequelize.Sequelize} */
    const sequelize = app.get('sequelize')

    sequelize.define('item', {
      _id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      text: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: true
      }
    }, {
      freezeTableName: true
    })
  }
}
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this. I always explicitly define the foreign key.Some thing like this.

```
ItemTranslation.belongsTo(sequelize.models.item,{foreignKey:'sourceId'})



Item.associate = function () {
      Item.hasMany(sequelize.models.ItemTranslation,{foreignKey:'sourceId'})
    }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work I'm afraid. Get the same error and everything.
I've also tryed to add the `targetId` to that second parameter object, but still nothing.

Comment: Could you please upload the screenshot of full error message.